# UnpackHtml is failing with latest version of Chilkat (9.5.0.93)

Tags: chilkat, chilkat-email

Using a previous version of chilkat (9.5.0.84) 32-bit Chilkat for .NET 4.7, we used mail.UnpackHtml successfully

After upgrading to the latest version of chilkat (9.5.0.93) UnpackHtml is returning false and not creating a html file

We are passing the directory path as a windows drive mapping "E:\tmp\mail" ; the call to UnpackHtml returns false and the file has not been created

However on further investigation, if the directory is passed as a UNC path “\localmachinename\e$\tmp\mail” - the call to UnpackHtml returned true and the file has been created

We need to upgrade to 9.5.0.93 to resolve an issue we had with connecting to Microsoft Graph, but this issue will cause us problems with our existing setup.

Answer (score 0):

The UnpackHtml methods was working as it should.  The mistake was in passing a full absolute file path in the 3rd argument (partsSubDir), which should've been just the name of the subdirectory.  See https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/csEmailRef.html#method178